# Is a closure a copy of the values to another position of memory?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures

I created the memoization bellow as a proof of concept. I wanted to discover the answer for the following question: When we modify a variable inside a closure, does it modify the original initial location in the memory? Or when a closure is created it copies all the values from the original location to another position in the memory? According to my test with the code bellow, it does a copy, but, the original location is also affected when the values inside the closure change. Test by yourself.

```js
class Memoization { 
    cacheInitValue = new Map();
    memoize(f) {
        let cache = this.cacheInitValue;
        return function (...args) {
            let cacheKey = f.name + JSON.stringify(args);
            if (cache.has(cacheKey)) {
                return cache.get(cacheKey);
            }
    
            let result = f.apply(this, args);
            cache.set(cacheKey, result);
            return result;
        };
    }
}

// Example of use #1: memoize simple function
// ----------------------------------------------------------------

function sum(...numbers) {
    console.log(`sum(${numbers.join(',')}) was called`);
    let total = 0;
    for (let n of numbers) {
        total += n;
    }
    return total;
}

// using:

let memoSum = new Memoization();
let cacheSum = memoSum.memoize(sum);

console.log(cacheSum(10,20)); // get result from function (first time)
console.log(cacheSum(10,20)); // get result from cache

// Now,take a look in the object memoSum has it property modified by the closure:

console.log(memoSum.cacheInitValue, "(see browser console)"); // the output is the keys of map changed inside the closure context. 

// Now is the weirdest part, force a reset the cacheInitValue and see what happens:

memoSum.cacheInitValue = new Map();

// Yeah… call again the memoized:

console.log(cacheSum(10,20));
```

Comment: I think modification depends on the engine used and the objects used to copy. `WebAssembly.Memory` has linear memory, so we can share that same memory, and make changes between and in different contexts.

Comment: A lexical closure environment containing references to the closed over elements referenced in the function is for the purpose of transparently keeping them from being garbage collected. This is a language facility not exposed to the programmer. This last is that JavaScript does allow one to pass, return, or store references. Parameters, return values, and variables all have by value semantics.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2}) !== JSON.stringify({b:2,a:1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't related to closures, you didn't overwrite `cache`.

1. you assign `initCacheValue` to `cache`. The both variables now point to the same object.
2. you change `initCacheValue` but that doesn't change `cache`. It still points to the old object.

The reason: object variables are references to objects, not objects themselves.

In your case resetting the cache could be:

```
memoSum.cacheInitValue.clear();
```

Comment: You helped me to clarify this problem. Thanks very much. So when we create new Map and assign it to the variable, it allocates a new position at RAM and stores it, preserving the original value in the old ram position, unless we use the clear() which I imagine clear the memory which also resets the closures references.

Comment: @Brainiac.jar clear is the method of Map. doesnt relate to clering an object from memory. objects are removed from memory automatically when no objects variables point to them

Comment: Ah yeah, of course I knew, I mentioned clear method of Map, I speculated its inside behavior is clear all the memory references.

Comment: @Brainiac.jar you might want to refrain from relying on assumptions about how the interpreter implements features.